# Plank is too hard to trigger

Tags: plank

I want the dock to be at the bottom, and hidden. I like the behavior I have on my home mac (I'm using eOS on my work computer) that shows the dock as soon as the pointer hovers it for some time, or if I hit the bottom "hard" (fast cursor movement toward the bottom edge).

I have hence selected auto-hide but none of the behaviors match what I want. First, they make little sense to me:

- **intellihide**: apparently similar to autohide but should be smarter (like don't hide if the desktop is apparent?)
- **autohide**: apparently similar to intellihide but dumber
- **dodge maximized window**: should hide only if the window is maximized?
- **window dodge**: should hide only if a window is covering it?
- **dodge active window**: should hide only if the active window is covering it?

Now, maybe I got them wrong, but I've tried them all.

The issue is that once hidden, the dock is a nightmare to reveal. I have to shake my mouse pointer, light a candle and pray for it to show up. I mean none of the expected behaviors trigger a reveal:

- sending the cursor on the bottom edge with a large velocity
- hovering the mouse for 250-500ms on the edge

But now, I actually don't know what triggers the dock to show up.
I can do the following and nothing will trigger:

- move the cursor slowly to the edge and hold the cursor still
- move the cursor fast to the edge and shake it
- hit the bottom edge hard
- ???

*(and admittedly, after writing this question and trying every scenario, the best success rate I have is when moving the cursor really slowly to the edge. but that's not a productive behavior)*

I did try to change the pressure reveal option, as I understand should avoid unwanted dock reveals; however even with this option disabled the dock is too hard to reveal.

Note: when I select autohide and disable pressure reveal, the behavior is nice as long as the settings are open (or for a short period of time). But quickly after that I have a hard time revealing the dock.

Answer (score 1):

Disable pressure reveal, hide delay 200, unhide delay 0 and autohide is ggod for me, thanks for pressure reveal tip.

Not that much sure why is it not saving your settings permanently

Comment: I switched to Docky but it's not perfect either. I'll try again with Plank and your suggestions, thanks a lot!

Comment: Still not good. Docky shows up instantly which cause lots of unwanted reveals. Plank is way to hard to trigger and I have to keep banging the cursor against the edge and shaking / waving / praying for the dock to show up. Still not as good as macOS unfortunately :(